# Powershell - Filter scope of line of a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, scope, filtering

As I am a newbie on powershell, I have tried a lot of thing, but I think I need realy help...

**Here is my problem:**
I want to filter a scope of line of a csv file to output the non filtered lines in powershell. Moreover, I want to filter the line who have the number "5" at their beginning.

**Here is the csv example file when I do the Powershell commands:**

```
FirstName      Name      PhoneNumber
A               AA            3366
B               BA            3356
C               CC            5898
D               DC            5316
E               EH            5623
F               FB            5963
```

Here, I want to filter the line who beginning by "5" and have a powershell output like that:

```
FirstName      Name      PhoneNumber
A               AA            3366
B               BA            3356
```

**Here is my powershell code:**

```
$i = "C:\my_csv_file.csv"
$colonne = "First Name" , "Name" , "PhoneNumber"
$test = Import-Csv -Encoding Default $i -Delimiter ";" | Select  $colonne
echo $test
```

I think (but i'm not sure) that what I have to do to filter is to use a "if" command.

Actually I have tried a lot of "if" with some arguments, but nothing work!

Hope you can help me guys!

*Sorry for my bad english, i've tried to write the better that i can. If you don't understand something, tell me, it will be a pleasure to argue more*

Comment: I don't see the number 5 at the beginning of any of the lines in the example.

Comment: @EBGreen They're at the start of the phone number field.

Comment: Aaah...I misunderstood the direction of the filter. I obviously need to wake up more.

Comment: Don't worry @EBGreen, Pieo said _I want to filter the line who have the number "5" at their beginning._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$i = 'C:\my_csv_file.csv'
$colonne = @('First Name', 'Name', 'PhoneNumber')
$test = Import-Csv -Path $i -Encoding Default -Delimiter ';' |
Where-Object { $_.PhoneNumber -notlike '5*' } |
Select-Object -Property $colonne
$test
```

Comment: Thanks! That made my day!

Comment: No problem. :).

Answer (score 1):

This will use regex to filter your `PhoneNumber` property:

```
$i = 'C:\my_csv_file.csv'
$colonne = @('First Name', 'Name', 'PhoneNumber')
$test = Import-Csv -Path $i -Encoding Default -Delimiter ';' |
    Where-Object { $_.PhoneNumber -notmatch '^5' } |
    Select-Object -Property $colonne
$test
```

This ([`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1)) will look at the property and remove the phone numbers starting with 5 from the end result.